# C++ program not working when asked for user input

Tags: c++

The following code converts a string to an integer array and outputs the sum of the array. It works if I define str in the program(str = "1 2 3 4 5") but not if the user inputs str. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening and would love some feedback!

```
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

// Fucntion to convert a string to 
// integer array 
void convertStrtoArr(string str) 
{ 
    // get length of string str 
    int str_length = str.length(); 

    // create an array with size as string 
    // length and initialize with 0 
    int arr[str_length] = { 0 }; 

    int j = 0, i, sum = 0; 

    // Traverse the string 
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) { 

        // if str[i] is ', ' then split 
        if (str[i] == ' ') { 

            // Increment j to point to next 
            // array location 
            j++; 
        } 
        else { 

            // subtract str[i] by 48 to convert it to int 
            // Generate number by multiplying 10 and adding 
            // (int)(str[i]) 
            arr[j] = arr[j] * 10 + (str[i] - 48); 
        } 
    } 

    cout << "arr[] = "; 
    for (i = 0; i <= j; i++) { 
        cout << arr[i] << " "; 
        sum += arr[i]; // sum of array 
    } 

    // print sum of array 
    cout << "\nSum of array is = " << sum << endl; 
} 

// Driver code 
int main() 
{ 
    
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    

    convertStrtoArr(str); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `getline(cin,str)`, cin reads to first white char.

Comment: Your code isn't valid C++ code, as C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `>>` on a stream reads one word at a time. So your string size will remain 1 always and you would not get correct results, So if you want to read whole string then use below methods.

```
cin.getline(str, sizeof str);
```

Or you can use this method also by playing around.

```
getline(cin, str);
```

Comment: `sizeof str` doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: "Using cin >> on a stream reads" ... `cin` **is** the stream, and you are confusing `sizeof str` with the length of the string, it is not the same